# Javascript sorting array by number then string and with other array affected

Tags: javascript

I have an object variable containing two arrays

```
var count = 200;

var display = {
   text: [5, 10, 25, 50, "All", 18],
   value: [5, 10, 25, 50, count, 18]
};
```

*notes: the string typed in text array will always refer to the count variable in value array*

I want to sort the text array by **number** first then **string**, but the value array are also affected based on text array in display variable so after sorting it will be outputting something like this:

```
display.text: [5, 10, 18, 25, 50, "All"];
display.value: [5, 10, 18, 25, 50, 200];
```

if i make the count value less, example

```
count = 1; // change count to 1
```

it will display something like this

```
display.text: [5, 10, 18, 25, 50, "All"];
display.value: [5, 10, 18, 25, 50, 1];
```

How to do it?

Comment: Rather than trying to sort two arrays together (which is a pain), create a single array made up of objects that contain both `text` and `value`: `var display = [ { text:5, value:5 }, ...etc ]`. Now you only have one array to sort.

Comment: Your desired sorting for your value array seems to have no other obvious logic than that the value 200 or 1 _was_ coming from a variable named `count` at some point – but there is no way of knowing that any more once your variable display is filled with its values.

Comment: @MattBurland Oh yeah! never thought of it, and all answers below suggest that too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var count = 200;
var display = {
   text: [5, 10, 25, 50, "All", 18],
   value: [5, 10, 25, 50, count, 18]
};

var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<display.text.length; i++) {
    array.push( { text: display.text[i], value: display.value[i] } );   
}

array = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aa = a.text, bb = b.text;
    if(typeof a.text == 'string' || a.text instanceof String) aa = +Infinity;
    if(typeof b.text == 'string' || b.text instanceof String) bb = +Infinity;
    return aa - bb;
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EAjts/)

If you want to mantain the object structure you can do this in the end:

```
var display_sorted = {
    text: [],
    value: []
};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    display_sorted.text.push(array[i].text);
    display_sorted.value.push(array[i].value);
}
```

[**Working demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/EAjts/1/)

Comment: Yay. Thank you! you're awesome. but i have question, what "+Infinity" stands for?

Comment: Glad it helped. `Infinity` is a variable in global scope. The initial value of `Infinity` is `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and its value is greater than any other number including itself. I used it to make `string` elements greater than any number in the sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to pair the corresponding array items, then `sort` them. The sort will need to check for the string type to place it at the end, and a regular numeric comparison will handle the rest.

```
var result = display.text.map(function(x, i) {
    return { text: x, value: display.value[i] };
  }).sort(function(x, y) {
    return typeof x.text === "string" ? 1 : x.text - y.text;
  });
```

Check out this [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/AcEReY/1/edit?js,console,output) of the same code.

Comment: Yay, thank you. This also works! and much simple answer. Did "array map" work in all browsers?

Comment: @klassen `map` should work with all browsers, and IE9+, according to the [Kangax compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map). If you need to support an earlier version of IE, and you have either jQuery or Lo-Dash (or Underscore) in your project, you can use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) or [_.map](http://lodash.com/docs#map) instead, respectively.